# JavaScript Concat Unicode

Tags: javascript, unicode, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate unicode in JavaScript and i'm getting this error "Invalid Unicode escape sequence". I have tried to search how to concatenate unicodes in javascript and i've seen many examples here on this site but nothing has worked for my code... I found something about using String.fromCharCode too but without a great example. So i could not figure it out.

So. Here is an example code

```
let test = "5000",
string;

let unicode = test.split()
for(let i = 0; i < unicode.length; i++) {
    string += "\u003"+unicode[i]+"\uFE0F\u20e3";
}

console.log(string);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to concatenate `\u003` before the item. Since it is not a unicode character, it is causing the error. Removing the problematic string should fix it.

Also, you have to provide `string` a default value before concatenating. Otherwise, it is `undefined`.

```js
let test = "5000",
  string = "";


let unicode = test.split('')

for (let i = 0; i < unicode.length; i++) {
  string += unicode[i] + "\uFE0F\u20e3";
}

console.log(string);
```

Comment: the unicode[i] returns a number so, my first number for variable test is 5 so it should be "\u0035\uFE0F\u20E3" for the first number and "\u0030\uFE0F\u20E3" for the other three "0" numbers

Comment: @TimLevinsson I've updated my answer. It should work now.

Comment: I see. It works now. But how do i get rid of the "<" arrows?